# How to $pull elements from an array, $where elements' string length > a large number?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

And old slash escaping bug left us with some messed up data, like so:

```
{
    suggestions: [
        "ok",
        "not ok /////////// ... 10s of KBs of this ... //////",
    ]
}
```

I would like to just pull those bad values out of the array. My first idea was to `$pull` based on a regex that matches 4 "/" characters, but it appears that regexes to not work on large strings:

```
db.notes.count({suggestions: /\/\/\/\//}) // returns 0
db.notes.count({suggestions: {$regex: "////"}}) // returns 0
```

My next idea was to use a `$where` query to find documents that have `suggestion` strings that are longer than 1000. That query works:

```
db.notes.count({
    suggestions: {$exists: true},
    $where: function() {
        return !!this.suggestions.filter(function (item) {
            return (item || "").length > 1000;
        }).length
    }
})
// returns a plausible number
```

But a `$where` query can't be used as the condition in a `$pull` update.

```
db.notes.update({
    suggestions: {$exists: true},
}, {
    $pull: {
        suggestions: {
            $where: function() {
                return !!this.suggestions.filter(function (item) {
                    return (item || "").length > 1000;
                }).length
            }
        }
    }
})
```

throws

```
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 81,
        "errmsg" : "no context for parsing $where"
    }
})
```

I'm running out of ideas. Will I have to iterate over the entire collection, and `$set: {suggestions: suggestions.filter(...)}` for each document individually? Is there no better way to clean bad values out of an array of large strings in MongoDB?

(I'm only adding the "javascript" tag to get SO to format the code correctly)

Comment: How many elements do you need to remove from the array?

Comment: Less than 20, from each array. Usually 1.

Comment: Also `db.notes.count({suggestions: /\/\//})`  should return the number of documents with `/` no matter the length of your string. That being said  for large string you should use the filter argument to the `updateOne()` method: `db.notes.updateOne({suggestions: /\/\//}, { "$pull": {suggestions: /\/\//}})`

Comment: tested  with `520000` characters string

Comment: I agree with @user3100115 here that the approach should be *"matching the element"* rather than trying to *"match on the size of the element"*. At any rate, the JavaScript expression to `$where` is not capable of working on "individual array elements", nor does the logic attempted even do this as it would still not identify the array member(s) to remove via `$pull`, but just tell you the array "contained" something matching the condition. Think of `$pull` in terms of arguments to `$elemMatch`, in which you also cannot apply a `$where` expression for the same reasons.

Comment: @user3100115 I have no idea why `db.notes.count({suggestions: /\/\/\/\//})` didn't work yesterday, but now, when I try it on a test case, it does work. Maybe there was some invisible Unicode chars separating the "/" chars, our content is all Arabic. Given that, `db.notes.updateOne({suggestions: /\/\//}, { "$pull": {suggestions: /\/\//}})` is a simple, correct solution to the problem as it is described here. Apparently, my real problem is different, and I ended up solving it with the brute force solution I mentioned at the end of the question, with a string length check, not a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution pointed out in the question comments should have worked. It does work with a test case that is a recreation of the original problem. Regexes can match on large strings, there is no special restriction there.

```
db.notes.updateOne({suggestions: /\/\//}, { "$pull": {suggestions: /\/\//}})
```

Since this didn't work for me, I ended up going with what the question discussed: updating all documents individually by filtering the array elements based on string length:

```
db.notes.find({
    suggestions: {$exists: true}
}).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.suggestions = doc.suggestions.filter(function(item) {
        return (item || "").length <= 1000;
    }); db.notes.save(doc);
});
```

It ran slow, but that wasn't really a problem in this case.